# How can I create a constructor that allows me to pass unassigned properties to a method without error?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, constructor

In the code below I pass several parameters to a method "***SendEmail()***".

The unassigned String property ***myEmail.ToAddress.Name*** passes without issue, but when Class property ***myEmail.Bcc.Email*** gets passed without a value I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

Can I modify my constructors to avoid this?

Thanks.

**Email Message Class**

```
Public Class EmailMessage

    Public Sub New()

        Dim ToAddress As New EmailAddress
        Dim FromAddress As New EmailAddress
        Dim Bcc As New EmailAddress
    End Sub

    Public Property ToAddress() As EmailAddress
        Get
            Return m_To
        End Get
        Set(value As EmailAddress)
            m_To = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_To As EmailAddress

    Public Property FromAddress() As EmailAddress
        Get
            Return m_From
        End Get
        Set(value As EmailAddress)
            m_From = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_From As EmailAddress

    Public Property Bcc() As EmailAddress
        Get
            Return m_Bcc
        End Get
        Set(value As EmailAddress)
            m_Bcc = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Bcc As EmailAddress

    Public Property Subject() As String
        Get
            Return m_Subject
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Subject = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Subject As String

    Public Property Body() As String
        Get
            Return m_Body
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Body = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Body As String

End Class
```

**Email Address Class**

```
Public Class EmailAddress

    Public Sub New()
        Dim Email As String = ""
        Dim Name As String = ""
    End Sub

    Public Property Email() As String
        Get
            Return m_Email
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Email = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Email As String

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Name As String
End Class
```

**Code**

```
    Public Sub AssignVariables()

        Dim myEmail As New EmailMessage
        Dim toAddress As New EmailAddress
        Dim fromAddress As New EmailAddress

        toAddress.Email = "example@example.com"
        fromAddress.Email = "example@example.com"

        myEmail.ToAddress = toAddress
        myEmail.FromAddress = fromAddress
        myEmail.Subject = "Example"
        myEmail.Body = "Example"

        Call SendEmail(myEmail)
    End Sub

    Public Sub SendEmail(ByVal email As EmailMessage)

        Send SendEmail(email.FromAddress.Email, email.ToAddress.Name, email.ToAddress.Email, email.Bcc.Email, email.Subject, email.Body)
    End Sub


    Private Sub SendEmail(fromAddress As String, toName As String, toAddress As String, bcc As String, subject As String, body As String)

    End Sub
```

Comment: its simple. the reason you get the null reference exception is because the property you are accessing - the object, is not instantiated. you should instantiate it in the constructor of the class so then you can access the property safely. Step through the debugger and make sure it is instantiated correctly.#

Comment: I can't use the dubugger at the moment as there is a partially completed module a partner is working on. Could I ask for an example please?

Comment: The `Dim ToAddress As New EmailAddress` inside the constructor is wrong. It just creates a local var that confusingly has the same name as  a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties should be defined as `ReadOnly`. Create a new instance of each property in the constructors if non are provided. Something like this:

```
Public Class EmailMessage

    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New([to] As EmailAddress, [from] As EmailAddress, bcc As EmailAddress)
        Me.m_To = If(([to] Is Nothing), New EmailAddress, [to])
        Me.m_From = If(([from] Is Nothing), New EmailAddress, [from])
        Me.m_Bcc = If((bcc Is Nothing), New EmailAddress, bcc)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property ToAddress() As EmailAddress
        Get
            Return m_To
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property FromAddress() As EmailAddress
        Get
            Return m_From
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Bcc() As EmailAddress
        Get
            Return m_Bcc
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Subject() As String
        Get
            Return m_Subject
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Subject = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Body() As String
        Get
            Return m_Body
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Body = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private ReadOnly m_To As EmailAddress
    Private ReadOnly m_From As EmailAddress
    Private ReadOnly m_Bcc As EmailAddress
    Private m_Body As String
    Private m_Subject As String 

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks! This has worked. AssignVariables() took some re-writing to get the code to work with the read only properties, and I also noticed it works without being read-only. Why is read-only recommended?

Comment: There's no right or wrong. It all depends on your needs. If you expect the properties to *always* be instantiated, then this is the way. If not, then you have to check for null reference before accessing the properties. `If (Not myEmail.ToAddress is Nothing ) Then myEmail.ToAddress.Name`. In the end, we are all victims of our own design;)

Comment: Well that's something to think about. Thanks.